# Problem when executing a simple C program in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I'm trying to run a simple C program in Eclipse and I am new to Eclipse.
When running the command I see output of the program for a very brief moment in the console, but instead for the program to wait for input, output disappears and and an empty console is shown instead. Is this a problem of the program or something related to the settings of the Eclipse IDE?

Edit: On the console menu there is a terminate button and when I pres it the output of the program shows but it doesn't wait for input and the program is terminated. Any help?

Image: [image: TerminatedProgram]

Here is the code

```
//The input is a series of numbers and the number X. Find
//how many times the number X is met in the series

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int m[20];
    int n, X, cnt=0;

    printf("Insert maximum length of the series (n<=20)\n");
    scanf("n= %d",&n);

    printf("Insert X the number you are looking for\n");
    scanf("X= %d",&X);

    while(n<1||n>20){
        printf("Bad input, n should be between 1 and 20\n");
        scanf("n= %d",&n);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &m[i]);
        if(m[i]==X)cnt++;
    }

    printf("X is found %d times\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the empty console:

[image: Empty console after showing for a very brief moment program output]

**Edit**: I've tried rewriting the code using `cout` and `cin` but then the compiler in Eclipse complains on the line `#include<iostream.h>` saying that there is an unresolved inclusion. Sounds like a separate question to me.

Comment: Please do not add a programming language tag that has nothing to do with your respective code.

Comment: `scanf("n= %d",&n);` --> `scanf("%d",&n);` otherwise you need to type "n =" to match with the pattern, same for the rest of `scanf`s, but this issue is not related with: _Empty console after showing for a very brief moment program output_

Comment: @Geno Hi Geno, this is a C/C++ project compiled with g++ so even if it is a C code it is compatible with C++ and someone with C++ knowledge could also reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: [click](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102569/)
Basically the output of the standard input output is buffered and `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` solves the problem.